# How to change UI without opening a new window in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt5

In my program, I'm moving from `QMainWindow` to `QDialog` on a press of a button.

I want to do the same without opening a new window and be able to move between the UI's.

The Target device will have a very small touchscreen, so I want my UI to *sit still* and require minimal repositioning.

Please point me in the right direction or give me an example on How-to.

Comment: You may want to remove the `qt-creator` from the title and tags. The actual problem is about `Qt` and is independent what IDE you use to develop your `Qt` applications.

Comment: How about using a [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you can use a [`QStackedWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qstackedwidget.html).
From the documentation:

> The QStackedWidget class provides a stack of widgets where only one widget is visible at a time.

Instead of opening a new window, push its content on top of the stack and pop it when you want to (let me say) *close the window*.
Each widget is a *page* of your application and no separate window is required. You can design them as you would design a central widget of a normal window or dialog.